# Unable to post values to a PHP page using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I want to post login email and password to a PHP page using AJAX

```
<form onsubmit="authenticate()">
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
function authenticate() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
var params = 'email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass; 
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/login/login.php";
httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST

httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length); // POST request MUST have a Content-Length header (as per HTTP/1.1)

httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
    if(httpc.responseText == "success") {
        window.location.replace("files.html");
    }
    else if (httpc.responseText == "fail")
        alert("Invalid details");        
}
httpc.send(params);
}
}
```

If the select query returns a row after authentication, it echoes "success, else it echoes "fail"

Comment: 1).Your  question is not clear.2).In your  Javascript how you  are passing the params?

Comment: I have a page `login.html` which has to POST data to `login.php` using AJAX. I got that on some tutorial, but that's not the only way i tried. I've been failing to get a result.

Comment: Try this tutorials... Without jquery 1).http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp . WIth Jquery 2).http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Comment: Isn't working. I don't know what is the issue. I have created PHP applications in the past, but all was under htdocs, but this html file isn't, and I can't keep it as a PHP page. I tried GET directly with PHP, so my PHP is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're sending your `params` from inside the function `onreadystatechange`, it probably doesn't work at all right now, because the "state" will change once you send something, but your code doesn't send anything until the "state" has changed... This should fix it:

```
function authenticate() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
var params = 'email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass; 
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/login/login.php";
httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST

httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length); // POST request MUST have a Content-Length header (as per HTTP/1.1)

httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
        if(httpc.responseText == "success") {
            window.location.replace("files.html");
        }
        else if (httpc.responseText == "fail")
            alert("Invalid details");      
        else
            alert(httpc.responseText);  
    }
    // Your httpc.send was here
}

httpc.send(params); // <-- should be here
}
```

You must also change your HTML to add a `return false;` after the call to the `authenticate` function, in order to prevent the form from doing its "default" action (submitting to itself, in "GET" mode).

```
<form onsubmit="authenticate(); return false;">
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What does it do exactly? Nothing? Or does it alert "Invalid details" every time? Also, could you please add the PHP code... it might help.

Comment: <?php
require "connect.php";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$SQL = "Select * from users where email='$email' AND password='$password'";
echo $SQL;
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
if($count == 1){
 echo "success";
}
else{
 echo "fail";
}
?>

Comment: No alert, no signs. All I see changing is the URL: www/index.html?email=keval&password=keval

Comment: Ignore the other echoes, it is the same without them.

Comment: Oh, yeah you must add `return false;` after your call to the `authenticate()` function to prevent the "default" action of the form element (in this case it submits to the current url, in "get" mode). Change it like this: `<form onsubmit="authenticate(); return false;">`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is the URL still changing to www/index.html?email=keval&password=keval?

Comment: No, now the URL won't change

Comment: Try adding another `else` in the `onreadystatechange` function and "alerting" the result... (I've updated my answer). Also, note that in your PHP you are assigning `$password = $_POST['pass'];`, but the input in your form is called "password", you should change it to `$password = $_POST['password'];`

Comment: Updated with another else, still won't give an output. And about pass & password thing, this is taking care of it `var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;`

Comment: A friend provided me AJAX code and it works. I had to add cross-domain posting by modifying the `login.php`'s header.